# How to identify in which syntax user has entered the data C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

In my project I am allowing user to enter data in two formats

1. `{objectname}`
2. `{ObjectName}`

```cs
if (NewDescription.Contains("{objectname}") || NewDescription.Contains("{inputvalue}") || NewDescription.Contains("{expectedvalue}"))
    NewDescription = NewDescription.Replace("{objectname}", objectName).Replace("{inputvalue}", inputValue).Replace("{expectedvalue}", expectedValue);
else
    NewDescription = NewDescription.Replace("{ObjectName}", objectName).Replace("{InputValue}", inputValue).Replace("{ExpectedValue}", expectedValue);
```

How can I identify and check which format user has entered in database?

Comment: I would just suggest you to use if else if ladder

Comment: I have edited your question a little to improve the formatting. Remember, here on Stack Overflow every user is encouraged to [edit] their questions to improve them as much as possible. If there is any more clarification you can add, to help us understand what you are trying to do, please do.

Answer (score 0):

Last part of your else is confusing,I am not sure what you are trying to acheive here.

```
 if (NewDescription.Contains("{objectname}") )
    {
       NewDescription = NewDescription.Replace("{objectname}", objectName);
    }
    else if(NewDescription.Contains("{inputvalue}"))
    {
    NewDescription = NewDescription.Replace("{inputvalue}", inputValue);
    }
    else if(NewDescription.Contains("{expectedvalue}"))
    {
    NewDescription = NewDescription.Replace("{expectedvalue}", expectedValue);
    }
        else
   label.Text="Wrong format";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution where I can just use regex, For e.g.

Regex.Replace(ButtonClick on {objectname}, {ObjectName}, ReplaceValue, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);